# How can I clean up unused and dead Firefox bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I use Firefox 3.5 with XMarks. Over the years I've accumulated lots and lots of bookmarks. Now most of them are likely to be irrelevant, dead or of no interest to me. What's the best way to clean that heap up? I am looking into doing the following:

- Identify and remove bookmarks that lead to dead sites (I learnt I could use AM-Deadlink for that. Are there better options?)
- Find bookmarks that I haven't used for long time, let's say a year, and remove them.

How can I accomplish those tasks?

Comment: Second one can't be done since firefox (nor chrome, afaik) doesn't keep history of bookmark clicking. Maybe there is some plugin which can compare your browsing history (if you keep it that long) with your current bookmarks, and get some results out of that, but that seems like a longshot to me.

Answer (score 1):

this might be helpful to you, it's an add-on for firefox
http://www.andyhalford.com/checkplaces/